# Mediapipe Hands landmark extraction

Tags: python, lstm, feature-extraction, gesture-recognition, mediapipe

My goal is to extract the hand landmarks from media pipe for each hand to train an LSTM network with and to recognize different actions.

With the Holistic solution, this is quite easy, since all landmarks of the left or right hand can be retrieved via the respective function.

```
def extract_keypoints(results):
    lh = np.array([[res.x, res.y, res.z] for res in results.left_hand_landmarks.landmark]).flatten() if results.left_hand_landmarks else np.zeros(21*3)
    rh = np.array([[res.x, res.y, res.z] for res in results.right_hand_landmarks.landmark]).flatten() if results.right_hand_landmarks else np.zeros(21*3)
    return np.concatenate([ lh, rh])
```

However, I get problems with hand detection when shooting from egoperspective and the holistic solution. So I have to switch to the mediapipe hands solution.
With mediapipe hands there is only the function MULTI_HAND_LANDMARKS, which only gives me the landmarks of one hand.

```
if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            print(results.multi_handedness)
            for hand_landmarks in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                print('hand_landmarks:', hand_landmarks)
            for hand_landmarks in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image,hand_landmarks,mp_hands.HAND_CONNECTIONS,mp_drawing_styles.get_default_hand_landmarks_style(),mp_drawing_styles.get_default_hand_connections_style())
```

As a result I get something like this, only 20 more times for the total of 21 landmarks per hand.

`hand_landmarks: landmark { x: 0.8579444885253906 y: 0.904037356376648 z: 2.08246397903622e-09 }`

Does the handlandmark output always alternate between one hand and the other if there are two hands in the picture?

Answer (score 0):

When you initialise `Hands` you have to set `max_num_hands=2`, like so:

```
with mp_hands.Hands(
        max_num_hands=2,
        model_complexity=1,
        min_detection_confidence=0.5,
        min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as hands:
```

and then `results.multi_hand_landmarks` is a list with two elements, where each element contains the landmarks of one hand